# I don't want my users to keep clearing their cache to view my website updates

Tags: caching

I need to find a way to set up my website so that whenever we make updates (which happens frequently) all the users can see them without the need for them to go to their browser options and keep clearing the cache. I cannot expect them to do this, most of them will not even know they have to do this and even if they did they would not want the hassle of doing this everytime. It's a risk that the site will not function correctly for users unless they clear their cache.

I read their might be a way to add code to each website page, does anyone know what most top level websites do to get past this issue?

Comment: What type of updates are you making? Content? Styles?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your headtags.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: While correct in some cases, this is usually undesirable. What OP wants is to set an expires or a last modified header.